# Ubuntu 20.04 green flickering + freeze

Tags: 20.04, freeze

I am having problem with Ubuntu 20.04. It's just freezes at the login screen and starts flickering (attached a photo). I tried editing boot options with "nomodeset" and I was able to log in successfully without any freezing and screen flickering. I also tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 version and had the same problem.

- Intel Core i3 6100U
- Intel HD Graphics 520

Any suggestions on how I can figure this out?

[Green flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXpg0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading to the latest Kernel version (5.8).